# Excel searching column and copying the cell next to it

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2007

i need to find the value from column C in the row B, and copy the value from found result in column D. If it's possible with formula and to copy formula to all cells in column D ? without VB?
Thanks for the help :)

```
A        B      C         D

1      | N   | Y      --> 2
-----------+-----+---
2      | Y   | Y      --> 2
-----------+-----+---
3      | V   | N      --> 1
-----------+-----+---
4      | F   | V      --> 3
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually, you would use a `VLOOKUP`, but the index and the values to be pulled are in the wrong order, in that case, use `INDEX` and `MATCH`:

```
=INDEX(A:A, MATCH(C1, B:B, 0))
```

Find the row in which C1 appears in column B, then from column A, take the value in the row that you just found.

So, for the first one, it looks for `Y` in column B, finds in in row 2, then take the value in column A and row 2.

Comment: WORKS GREAT! :)

Comment: @user339153 Awesome, thank you! :)